# Oracle Sql getting the value that appears most times for each different value of another column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So lets say that i have this table

```
language | offer
chinese  |   1
chinese  |   1
english  |   1
spanish  |   2
spanish  |   2
italian  |   2
french   |   3
```

and I want the languange that appears most times for each different offer,like this

```
language | offer
chinese  |   1
spanish  |   2
french   |   3
```

How do I do this in oracle sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it using `common table expression`s.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac11a/4)

In the first cte, you calculate  the counts grouped by offer and language.
 In the next cte, use `rank` or `row_number` to assign `1` to the offer with the highest language count.
 Finally, select from the 1st ranked rows.

```
with counts as(
select offer, language, count(*) cnt
from tablename
group by offer, language)
,ranking as
(select rank() over(partition by offer order by cnt desc) rnk
, c.*
from counts c)
select language, offer
from ranking 
where rnk = 1
```

Alternate approach without window functions:

```
with counts as (
select offer, language, count(*) cnt
from tablename
group by offer, language)
,maxcount as (select offer, max(cnt) mxcnt from counts group by offer)
select c.language, m.offer
from counts c
join maxcount m on m.offer = c.offer and m.mxcnt = c.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number in oracle for your output.

```
 SELECT LANGUAGE
        ,offer
    FROM (
        SELECT LANGUAGE
            ,offer
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY offer ORDER BY count(offer) DESC
                ) AS rno
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY LANGUAGE
            ,offer
        )
    WHERE rno = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a standard way to solve the problem:

```
select offer, language
from tablename t
group by offer, language
having not exists
(
  select 1
  from tablename
  where offer = t.offer
  group by language
  having count(language) > count(t.language)
)
```

In the main query you group each language per offer and check in the subquery that no other language group from the same offer contains more occurrences.